# enable dapr gRPC leads to 503 errors

Tags: dapr, azure-container-apps

I enabled the gRPC protocol on one of my container apps & now service invocation is failing.  I'm guessing I'm missing another step? ‍♂️

```
az containerapp dapr enable --name blah
                            --resource-group blah
                            --dapr-app-protocol grpc
```

> fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
> Connection id "0HMI4QJ3KEQS9", Request id "0HMI4QJ3KEQS9:00000002": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
> Dapr.Client.InvocationException: An exception occurred while invoking method: 'blah' on app-id: 'blah'
> ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 503 (Service Unavailable).
> at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
> at Dapr.Client.DaprClientGrpc.InvokeMethodAsync[TResponse](HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> ...

Comment: Could you add code for your apps? GRPC protocol requires explicit changes in your app to invoke based on GRPC.

Comment: oh, I thought using the DaprClient made it magically but [I guess not](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/dapr-for-net-developers/service-invocation#invoke-grpc-services-using-daprclient), thanks!  @JJ.

Answer (score 0):

GRPC protocol requires explicit server and client grpc based container apps.